# getClass() as Hashmap parameter

Tags: java, parameters, hashmap, key

My problem is, that I want to do something like this:

```
public abstract class ClassA{
    HashMap<Byte, Class<? extends ClassA> > hashMapWhichKeyIsEqualToTypeOfExtensionClass;

    public ClassA(){
        hashMapWhichKeyIsEqualToTypeOfExtensionClass = new HashMap<Byte, getClass()>();
    }
}
```

In other words I want HashMap's key types to be exact to the class, which is containing it, so as to

```
public class ClassB extends ClassA{
    public ClassB iAmHereJustToShowWhatDoIwantToGet(Byte index){
        return hashMapWhichKeyIsEqualToTypeOfExtensionClass.get(index);
    }
}
```

could work without casting ".get(index)" to ClassB.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: why don't you want to cast? ClassB knows its a subclass of ClassA, but it also knows that its HashMap is a Map of Byte to any type of ClassA. One safe way to cast is to check first if the object returned by .get(index) is an instance of ClassB, and if it is cast it to ClassB. Else throw an exception

Comment: I can do it eventually, but I wanted to ensure if there doesn't exist more-proper and more comfortable way.